Spring batch Jdbc cursor ItemReader refresh issue
I have a tasklet which reads the data based on update query. I need to read data which is marked to read from table1. I am getting an issue that after my update query I need to re-set the sql in reader to refresh it. Is there any way without re-setting the sql my reader can get the updated results from update query?
        public Step Step1(JobRepository jobRepository, PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws IOException {
            return new StepBuilder("Step1", jobRepository)
            .tasklet(new MyTasklet(reader(), dataSource), transactionManager)
                    .build();
        }

     @Component
    public class  MyReader extends JdbcCursorItemReader<Entity> {    
        private static final String sqlStr = "SELECT  * FROM table1, table2 WHERE table1.STATUS = 'ACTIVE' AND table1.ID=table2.REFID";
    
        public MyReader (DataSource dataSource) {
            setName(getClass().getSimpleName());
            setDataSource(dataSource);
            setSql(sqlStr);
            setRowMapper(new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Entity.class));
        }
    
        public void refresh () {
            setSql(sqlStr);
        }
    
    }

      public class MyTasklet implements Tasklet {
        private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    
        private MyReader reader;
       
        public MyTasklet(MyReader reader, DataSource dataSource) {
            this.reader = reader;
            this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        }
        
        @Override
        public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
            ExecutionContext executionContext = chunkContext.getStepContext().getStepExecution().getExecutionContext();
    
            if (rowsupdate == 0) {
                String updateQuery = "UPDATE table1 SET STATUS = 'ACTIVE' WHERE ROWNUM <= 100";
                rowsupdate = jdbcTemplate.update(updateQuery);           
            }
    
            if (rowsupdate > 0) {
                if (!readerInitialized) {
                    reader.open(executionContext);
                    reader.refresh();
                    readerInitialized = true;
                }
    
                Entity entity = reader.read();
    
                if (reader != null) {
                   // add data to list for write
                } else {
                    //pass list to writer
                    reader.close();
                    readerInitialized = false;
                    rowsupdate = 0;
                    //mark records from active to inactive
                }
            } else {
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
            }
    
            reader.update(executionContext);
            return RepeatStatus.CONTINUABLE;
        }
        
       }

